# why thymectomy doesn't lead to humoral immunity deficiency?

Tags: immunology

thymus is a place where T cells educate. in all textbooks it says if you remove thymus you will have cellular immunity deficiency. so in that case you should also be humoral immunity  deficient,then why it is only the cellular immunity which is ruined?

Comment: It depends on what age the thymus is removed. There are studies that suggest after a certain age, a thymectomy has no significant effect on the human T cell compartment.

Comment: A similar question from me. Though not happy with the answer. http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44103/does-atrophy-of-the-thymus-not-effect-t-cell-selection-and-tolerance